# Loading TypeScript module with submodules in SystemJS

Tags: javascript, typescript, systemjs

How do I load modules with SystemJS if they are generated by TypeScript as a single file containing several sub modules?

Currently, I have a larger library named *form* which is build in a single file containing multiple sub-modules (like packages). To generate the library file I use this tsconfig:

```js
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES5",
    "module": "system",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noResolve": true,
    "outFile": "../dist/lib/form.js",
    "declaration": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "lib",
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "filesGlob": [
    "**/*.ts"
  ]
}
```

As the result, I get a *form.js* file which contains the modules, which itself contain the classes and so on.

Now I want to use this generated library inside another project named *shop*. But every time I try to use classes from the sub-modules, SystemJS tries to load the submodules from a subdirectory instead from the library itself.

For example:

```js
import {Version}       from 'form';            // loaded from 'form.js'
import {ObservableSet} from 'form/collection'; // loaded from 'form/collection.js'
import {Button}        from 'form/ui/control'; // loaded from 'form/ui/control.js'
```

But i want to load all of them only from *form.js*, because 'form/collection' and 'form/ui/control' are modules defined within *form.js*. The files *form/collection.js* and 'form/ui/control.js' don't exist.

So, how would I modify the following configuration for SystemJS, so that it would load all three classes from *form.js*?

```js
System.config({
    baseURL: '.',
    defaultExtension: 'js',
    paths: {
        '*': '*.js'
    },
    map: {
        'form':       'lib/form',
        'shop':       'lib/shop',
        'is':         'lib/is',
        'jquery':     'lib/jquery-2.1.4'
    }
});

System.import('shop');
```

Directory layout:

```
/lib/form.js         (the module file, containing multiple modules)
/lib/shop.js         (the application)
/lib/...
/config.js           (config for systemjs, as shown)
/index.html
```

Answer (score 0):

I missed that SystemJS has a *bundles* option. The following addition lets SystemJS know that this modules should be loaded after loading the 'form' module, which itself provides all the mentioned modules, so that it won't attempt loading them from a different file.

```
bundles: {
  'form': ['form/collection', 'form/ui/control']
}
```

**Notice 1:**
Make sure that your bundle has not the same name as one of the imported modules. This results in a naming conflict. The following example will most likely cause trouble, because `form` is used twice, naming the bundle as well as a module inside the bundle:

```
bundles: {
  'form': ['form', 'form/something']
}
```

**Notice 2:** SystemJS supports wildcards in bundles. But they aren't deep. This means that `form/*` will add the module `form/collection`, but it won't add `form/ui/control`. To add also every module under `form/ui` it needs the additional entry `form/ui/*`.

Example:

```
bundles: {
  'form': ['form/*', 'form/ui/*']
}
```